# Allow only numbers and letters in an input box or textarea

Tags: php, regex

I have s form and I want to make it safe so I want to validate each input value before I save it in my database. For example I have this input field:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" />
```

and now for example, someone fills it with something other than numbers and letters like

```
myusername12|\/+*()!#$%^@^&_-+=.,';"
```

which might be dangerous values. So I want to check first if the field contains only letters and numbers and echo "letters and numbers only" otherwise. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/', $username) {
    echo "Looks good\n";
} else {
    echo "Invalid character\n";
}
```

And, if you want to be unicode compatible:

```
if (preg_match('/^\p{Xan}+$/', $username) {
    echo "Looks good\n";
} else {
    echo "Invalid character\n";
}
```

Where `\p{Xan}` stands for any alpha-numeric.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a handy built in function to perform this test.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php

Check this function returns true before attempting to save the data but make sure you're running DB prep anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer for your problem, but html5 can do this for you:

```
<input type="text" name="username" pattern="![^a-zA-Z0-9]" title="Only digits and letters" />
```

If the users blurs the input, it will highlight red (in FF at least). Be aware though, this is clientside. You can use the exaxt same regex in php to validate.

---

You can also save the regex and use it in both:

```
$regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9]";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    echo preg_match('/'.$regex.'/', $_POST['username']) ? 'match' : 'no match';
}

echo '<input name="username" pattern="'.$regex.'" title="Only digits and letters" />';
```

Small note: I dont know if browsers do complex regexes (or do them differently).

Comment: You shouldn't rely on client side validation as user can tweak them easily using tools like firebug

Comment: Hence the 'not a complete answer'. I'll add it in the post

Comment: i like the regex type but doesnt work, it return "match" either the values contains the unwanted character nor only letters and numbers

Comment: changed the regex, might work. It's a bit more thinking in html.

Comment: This regex matches `,;:!§/.abc123$*ù^~#{[`.